# LINQ Error Invalid Column Name on Group by sum

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

For some reason, when using two sums on a group by, i run into the error "invalid column name 'id'. When i only do one sum, it works as expected.

The following **fails** and throws the error:

```
from pd in PrDetails.Where(_pd => _pd.PrId == 46)
    group pd by new { pd.ProgramFund, pd.ProjectDetail.CostCenter, pd.ProjectDetail.Wbs }
    into g
select new
    {
        g.Key.ProgramFund,
        g.Key.CostCenter,
        g.Key.Wbs,
        CommittedTotal = g.Sum(_pd => _pd.PrDetailPrAmounts.Sum(_pa => _pa.CommittedAmount)),
        OverheadTotal = g.Sum(_pd => _pd.PrDetailPrAmounts.Sum(_pa => _pa.OverheadAmount))
    }
```

However, the following **does** work fine:

```
from pd in PrDetails.Where(_pd => _pd.PrId == 46)
    group pd by new { pd.ProgramFund, pd.ProjectDetail.CostCenter, pd.ProjectDetail.Wbs }
    into g
select new
    {
        g.Key.ProgramFund,
        g.Key.CostCenter,
        g.Key.Wbs,
        CommittedTotal = g.Sum(_pd => _pd.PrDetailPrAmounts.Sum(_pa => _pa.CommittedAmount))
    }
```

**And also**, when I get the overhead total, instead of the committed total, it works great:

```
from pd in PrDetails.Where(_pd => _pd.PrId == 46)
        group pd by new { pd.ProgramFund, pd.ProjectDetail.CostCenter, pd.ProjectDetail.Wbs }
        into g
    select new
        {
            g.Key.ProgramFund,
            g.Key.CostCenter,
            g.Key.Wbs,
            OverheadTotal = g.Sum(_pd => _pd.PrDetailPrAmounts.Sum(_pa => _pa.OverheadAmount))
        }
```

Why can't i get the committed total and overhead total at the same time?

I have our basic table structure below:

### PrDetails

Id (int)
PrId (int)
ProgramFund  (linq class)
ProjectDetail (linq class)

### ProjectDetails

Id (int)
CostCenter (linq class)
Wbs (linq class)

### PrAmounts

Id (int)
PrDetailId (int)
CommittedAmount (decimal)
OverheadAmount  (decimal)

Comment: do you have any associations/relationships set up for any of the tables?

Comment: Yea, all the relationships exist. If the relationships weren't there, the last two LINQ queries would not have been able to run successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the only think I can think it might be is a conflict with the names of your parameters. Try this:

```
from pd in PrDetails.Where(_pd => _pd.PrId == 46)
group pd by new { pd.ProgramFund, pd.ProjectDetail.CostCenter, pd.ProjectDetail.Wbs }
into g
select new
{
    g.Key.ProgramFund,
    g.Key.CostCenter,
    g.Key.Wbs,
    CommittedTotal = g.Sum(_pd1 => _pd1.PrDetailPrAmounts.Sum(_pa1 => _pa1.CommittedAmount)),
    OverheadTotal = g.Sum(_pd2 => _pd2.PrDetailPrAmounts.Sum(_pa2 => _pa2.OverheadAmount))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be starting a SQL profiler and checking the exact SQL being produced to start with and that should head you in the right direction